# Flex issue: border shown when drag-n-drop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm attempting to use "mx:HorizontalList" to take advantage of its build-in support for drag-n-drop operations. Since I don't want the list to show the border, I set "borderVisible" to "false", which works as expected. However, whenever the drag-n-drop is being performed and an element is being moved from its original position to the new position, a border in light blue color shows up. Once the drag-n-drop is completed, the border goes away and everything is back to normal.Is there way to make it not show the border even during the drag-n-drop? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make focusAlpha equal to zero. Hope this solves your problem